# Finder does not show Path Bar and Status Bar, what to do?

Tags: macos, finder, ios

I have OS X Lion and when I open a finder window everything seems OK.
But I can't see the Path Bar nor the Status bar.

When I activate one of the bars with View->Show Status Bar or View->Show Path Bar the Finder window gets bigger in height ( growing downwards ), nothing else happens.

Anyone have an idea what I can do to see the Bars?

(The Bars are working in other applications like Safari, ⌘+/ and it pops up)

Comment: If you create a new user account, do they appear in that account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Finder plist. You can find it at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist.

Then restart. This should reset any strange preferences keeping the Finder from showing the path and status bars.

Comment: I restarted it, nothing changed. Do you have the same problem or does it work for you?

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the Finder plist before restarting. Does that fix it?

Comment: In Lion you can't see the Library by default. If you option click the Finder "Go" menu you can see and select the Library and open it.

Comment: I used Houdine to toggle visibility of the Library folder :D

Comment: The error occurs sometimes now... but it disappears when I do your trick with deleting the plist

Comment: It may be Houdine or something causing these errors if they aren't fully compatible with Lion. You may want to check that too.

Answer (score 5):

Is it just this you are looking for? Finder > View > Show Path Bar?

Also here: http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/findertip1.htm

Comment: I know what it is, it just doesn't show up sometimes, so I have to reboot :(. It's a bug, like the one not displaying the desktops in mission control. (and I have a new MacBook Pro)

Answer (score 2):

The bug did come from BetterSnapTool. An app for resizing the windows.

Comment: And how did you solve it? Remove BetterSnapTool, upgrading to a lion-compatible version or something else?

Comment: I didn't solve it, right now with the newest patches for OS X Lion and Better Snap Tool the bug persists. I wrote an email with a picture to the developer 3 months ago.