# Where did the info at the bottom of the Finder window go?

Tags: finder

I've re-installed my old system (10.7.5) and "*things are different!"*

Is there a setting somewhere I need to change?  I always used to see useful information at the bottom of a Finder window in *list view* and in other views.

I remember a series of small Folder icons representing the path, into which I could drag files, or click to move to that folder. Also the total number of files, and number of files currently selected. Oh, sometimes the available space left on the volume as well!

Now there's nothing at the bottom of the window at all!

[image: Screen Shot 2016-04-14 2]

[image: Screen Shot 2016-04-14 3]

Comment: related question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/234907/143729)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this question be helpful ? It gives at least a searchable option using "**View -> Show Status Bar**" or "**View -> Show Path Bar**".
(Sorry I can't just write this as a comment yet).

[Finder does not show Path Bar and Status Bar, what to do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20189/finder-does-not-show-path-bar-and-status-bar-what-to-do)

Comment: Geez I never thought to look in the pull-down menus for a Finder window but of course I should have. Reinstalls are always a trauma for me :)  Thank you!  If you are feeling lucky take a look [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/234907/143729) also.

Comment: I didn't see that question primarily because I had no idea what they were called, ergo:  "... *the info at the bottom of the Finder window* ..."

Comment: I have had this problem before, it also disappeared from Spotlight, that I got used to for my searches, replacing *Cmd + F* -- I think now you have to keep *Alt* pressed to see the path.
For your other question (about renaming files from the 'window title' bar), I have no idea, but I doubt you can do anything about it.